# BubbleSort using integer Array

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

I have been trying to implement Bubble Sort using simple integer array in java. However there seems to be some problem. Now i know that using ArrayList would be the best option and I would do that too. But why isnt it getting sorted with simple integer array.Here is the code

```
package sort;

public class BubbleSort {

    int array[]={1,5,3,32,54,6,87,5,1};
    int temp=0;
public void enter(){
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<(array.length-i);j++){
            if(array[j]>=array[j+1]){


                temp=array[j];
                array[j]=array[j+1];
                array[j+1]=temp;
                }

        }
    }
}
public void show(){

    for(int i:array){
    System.out.println(i);
    }
}
public static void main(String str[]){

    new BubbleSort().Enter();
    new BubbleSort().Show();
}
}
```

Its producing the same array as entered. Nothing is getting changed. The difference between a simple array and an ArrayList or Vector ,is just that they offer dynamic time expansion of array size.Is there anything more to it? I mean does simple array creates a different instance every time it is manipulated, just like Strings? It does seem to do so here.

Comment: Please note that it is convention in Java for package names to be lower-case, and method names to be camelCase. See http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch07_01.htm. It is surprisingly confusing when Java developers read code that violates this.

Comment: No this is not homework. And I am using eclipse This particular package has all the sorting programs. I dont know how to rename it.I know its not the right convention. I'll keep that in mind next time.Thank you that was so helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're not assigning a name to the instantiation of your BubbleSort class.

```
new BubbleSort().Enter();
new BubbleSort().Show();
```

Your code creates a new BubbleSort class, and then sorts it. And then it creates another new (and completely separate) BubbleSort class, and displays that one instead - and it hasn't been sorted.

You want to give a name to your variable, so you can sort it and then display it, like this:

```
BubbleSort myBubbleSort = new BubbleSort();
myBubbleSort.Enter();
myBubbleSort.Show();
```

As a side note (and as pointed out in SiB's answer), you may also want to check out the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html). Following these conventions makes your code more legible to other Java programmers, and includes things like using `lowerCamelCase` for method names, and `UpperCamelCase` for class names.

Comment: Thank you !! How did I miss that !

Answer (score 5):

Because you are **sorting one instance and showing another.**

```
new BubbleSort().Enter();
new BubbleSort().Show();
```

Use

```
BubbleSort bubbleSort = new BubbleSort();
bubbleSort.Enter();
bubbleSort.Show();
```

Also **you should rename `Enter()` to `enter()` and `Show()` to `show()`** to say the least.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are creating two different BubbleSort Objects, sorting the first one and displaying a different one.

It should have been....

```
public static void main(String str[]){

    BubbleSort sort = new BubbleSort();
    sort.Enter();
    sort.Show():

}
```

Answer (score 1):

And the correct BubbleSort code is:

```
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < (array.length - i); j++) {
            if (array[j - 1] > array[j]) {
                temp = array[j - 1];
                array[j - 1] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }

        }
    }
```

I hope it helps someone else looking for it.